# Converting a single variable of integers from json to a python list

Tags: python, json, list

Excuse my newbieness but I cannot find the solution.

I am using an API that returns my data in json, and after manipulation I need to turn it into a python list so I can do further calculation using each index as an integer from the list.

The json output is targeted to a variable and its output looks ok, but it is not as a list of the numbers.

Here is my code example:

```
import requests 
import json 
import time
import calendar
import pendulum
from mytoken import token


# Change serial
my_serial_numbers = ['123456789']

for serial in my_serial_numbers:
    try:
        recording_availibility_api = requests.get('https://api.sample.com/'+serial+'/path...',headers={"content-type": "application/json", "Authorization":"Bearer " + token})
        recordings_files = json.loads(recording_availibility_api.content.decode('utf-8'))
        for camId1 in (recordings_files['data'][0]['intervals']):
            cameraId1 = camId1.pop('end')
            dt_camera1 = pendulum.parse(cameraId1)
            time_camera1 = dt_camera1.int_timestamp
            time_camera1_str = str(time_camera1)
            print(time_camera1_str)
    except KeyError:
        print('edge is offline')
    continue
```

Output:

```
1641055957
1641104678
1641109926
1641142409
1641228862
1641237806
1641245124
1641306172
1641313527
1641315317
1641317850
1641320175
1641367757
1641383666
```

What I am trying to achieve:
[   1641055957,
1641104678,
1641109926,
1641142409,......]

I am attempting to have each of these outputs as an index in a list.

Much appreciated for any guidance.

Comment: You can use `recording_availibility_api.json()` directly, it has the same effect as `json.loads(recording_availibility_api.content())`.

Comment: You write that you want these outputs "as an index in a list", but do you perhaps mean "as an **element** in a list"?  An index of an item within a list is the position of the item within the list, e.g. 0 for the first item, 1 for the second, and so on.  Elements are the things in the list. If numbers such as 1641055957 are to be indexes, then you'll either need a list of length ~1.6 billion (which will use a huge amount of memory) or you'll have to use the dictionary approach as described in the answer below.  If the numbers will be elements, your list would have length about 14.

Comment: I meant that I would need the elements, but they will need to be in a list which is what I cannot achieve. I can only get the first element in a list, but not the rest. And I can have a case where the could be more than 14 elements as I showed in my example output.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, then you need to create a new list for the items read (I've named it `time_strs` in the code below) and `.append` your items to this list:

```py
# imports not repeated

# Change serial
my_serial_numbers = ['123456789']

time_strs = []

for serial in my_serial_numbers:
    try:
        recording_availibility_api = requests.get('https://api.sample.com/'+serial+'/path...',headers={"content-type": "application/json", "Authorization":"Bearer " + token})
        recordings_files = json.loads(recording_availibility_api.content.decode('utf-8'))
        for camId1 in (recordings_files['data'][0]['intervals']):
            cameraId1 = camId1.pop('end')
            dt_camera1 = pendulum.parse(cameraId1)
            time_camera1 = dt_camera1.int_timestamp
            time_camera1_str = str(time_camera1)
            time_strs.append(time_camera1_str)
    except KeyError:
        print('edge is offline')
    continue

print(time_strs)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intended to have these an an index in a list, you have the problem that you would need a list of length ~1641383666 (just taken one of the outputs here for reference). A better way in Python is to use a dictionary, like so:

```
myDictionary = {}
```

Then, to assign:

```
myDictionary[1641383666] = None
```

and to access:

```
x = myDictionary[1641383666]
```

EDIT:
having seen your intended output now, the solution is much clearer. If you only want a list of numbers, don't use the dictionary. Simply use the .append(item) at the end of each iteration and use a standard list.

```py
timestamps = []


#then at the print statement

timestamps.append(timestamp)
```

Comment: Each number in my output would need to be in 1 list and accessible. Do I still need the dictionary method?

Comment: The list needs to be what my output currently is, but in list format. I will need to compare 2 lists against eachother calculating each index from list 1 to the same index of list 2.

Comment: dictionaries support unlimited items. The list would work, but it would be so long the memory usage would be too great to be effective. you could iterate through and add each one. A list is therotically possible, a dictionary is better. Simply add a dictionary definition at the start, and where you print, add myDictionary[time_camera1_str] = whatever_you_want.

Comment: Thanks - i still dont understand how to do it from Syntax perspective. It only assings the first element: ['1641383665']. If this helps, my variable has many strings: <class 'str'>
1641104678
<class 'str'>
1641109926
<class 'str'>
1641142409
<class 'str'>
1641228862
<class 'str'>
1641237806
<class 'str'>
1641245124
<class 'str'>
1641306172
<class 'str'>
1641313527
<class 'str'>
1641315317
<class 'str'>
1641317850
<class 'str'>
1641320175
<class 'str'>
1641367757
<class 'str'>
1641383666
<class 'str'>

Comment: Or output looks like this as well: ['1641055957']
['1641104678']
['1641109926']
['1641142409']
['1641228862']
['1641237806']
['1641245124']
['1641306171']
['1641313527']
['1641315315']
['1641317850']
['1641320175']
['1641367757']
['1641383665']

Comment: Having seen your edit, I've provided a better solution

Comment: Much appreciated